# Excel, Write a value based on a counter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What I want to achieve is very simple. Based on the value of an Excel cell (let's consider it X), I want to write a specific value in X subsequent cells.

For example, if A1 has the number 3, a formula should write the word "TEST" in cells, let's say B1 to B3. If I change the value of A1 to 5, B4 and B5 should be automatically updated with the value "TEST".

In other words I want to keep a kind of a counter or execute a loop.

I searched the internet for something similar, but without success.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Solve it with some VB programming. I don't recommend it, so I'll
   leave it for someone else to write the code if you really want this.
2. Copy-paste a formula in the cells that should contain your "TEST" text. Here is how to do that:

   - Put your number in cell A1
   - Put the following formula in cel B1:

     > =IF( COUNTIF( $A$1:A1; "*" ) < $A$1; "TEST"; "" )
   - Copy-paste the formula in B1 to the right, as far as you'd like/need to.
   - Optionally, put an emergency brake in cell A2:

     > =IF( $A$1 > COUNTIF( 1:1; "*" ); "Warning: number too big!"; "" )